# LXC: Linux devices don't work within container

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, lxc

With Debian lenny I am desperately trying to get LXC working (Debian kernel 3.16 and LXC 1). One big issue is the use of device nodes. I use `lxc.autodev` and `lxc.cgroup.devices.allow` and my config looks like:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = br-lan
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/vz/private/210
# Common configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/debian.common.conf
# Container specific configuration
lxc.mount = /var/lib/lxc/core/fstab
lxc.utsname = core
lxc.autodev = 1
lxc.kmsg = 0
# /dev/urandom
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:9 rwm
```

In my opinion, everything should be correct here. However, inside the container only root has access to /dev/urandom:

```
# ls -l /dev/urandom
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 9 Okt  4 13:06 /dev/urandom
# stat /dev/urandom
   Datei: /dev/urandom
   Größe: 0              Blöcke: 0          EA Block: 4096   zeichenorientierte Spezialdatei
Gerät: 5h/5d    Inode: 28959       Verknüpfungen: 1     Gerätetyp: 1,9
Zugriff: (0666/crw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Zugriff    : 2017-10-04 13:06:01.251962498 +0000
Modifiziert: 2017-10-04 13:06:01.251962498 +0000
Geägndert   : 2017-10-04 13:06:01.251962498 +0000
Geburt    : -
# su mail -s /bin/bash
$ stat /dev/urandom
stat: der Aufruf von stat für '/dev/urandom' ist nicht möglich: Keine Berechtigung
```

Id est, as non-root user *within* the container, access to a device (/dev/urandom) is not possible, although the permissions are correct. As root *within* the container, it works.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of `/dev` (`ls -ld /dev`)? It should have execute permission for the user you want to access `/dev/urandom` (generally it has execute permission for everyone).

Comment: Yes, as can be seen in the post. It is rw for everyone. I don't think it has to be rwx; in all my other systems it's rw as well and I can read form /dev/urandom once it's "r" permissions.

Comment: Not `/dev/urandom`, `/dev` itself

Comment: Wow, indeed! Add it as answer. Somehow they permissions are 700. Just need to find out why. That's probably another question ...